# ListView DrawSubItem bad quality text

Tags: vb.net

I am using a `listview` with owner drawing enabled and I have three main problems

1 - I cannot get the right bounds of the first zero based subitem if its column's display index <> 0

2 - the drawn text hasn't a good quality even I set e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality

3 - When I draw from right to left the numbers doesn't  appear in HINDI shape (only on Windows 8 and later)

that's my code

```
e.DrawDefault = False
e.DrawBackground()
e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, e.SubItem.Font, New SolidBrush(e.SubItem.ForeColor), e.Bounds, New StringFormat(If(Me.RightToLeft, 1, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First Question:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc2266d5-5d51-49c2-8d9a-cb1dcc086cfa/listviewsubitem-bounds?forum=winforms

Second Question:

e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias

Still trying with the last one